# Different results using randomForest::randomForest with one tree vs rpart

Tags: r, regression, random-forest, rpart

I am wondering what randomForest package handles differently for each individual tree.

If I build a random forest with a single tree, no resampling, and allow the usage of all features in a dataset, I should get the same results as those obtained building a rpart model. I use the default configuration, which builds a tree with at least 5 elements for each leaf.

Instead, I am obtaining different results (better results with randomForest), as if the randomForest tree were able to better adapt to the data. Actually, we can see that rpart prediction is *layered*, something reasonable given the if-else nature of trees, but that the prediction for randomForest is not, as if it were ignoring `nodesize`.

This is a MVE illustrating this (note that `cp = 0` allows rpart trees to be built without restriction):

```
data("swiss")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

rf <- randomForest::randomForest( x = swiss[, 1:5], y = swiss[,6], mtry = 5 ,ntree = 1, replace = FALSE, nodesize = 5, sampsize = nrow(swiss))
plot(matrix(swiss[,6]), predict(object = rf, newdata = swiss[,-6]), ylim = c(10,30),  xlim = c(10,30), main = "RF tree", ylab = "Predicted", xlab = "Observed")
lines(seq(0,30), seq(0,30))

rp <- rpart::rpart(formula = Infant.Mortality ~ ., data = swiss, minbucket = 5, minsplit = 5, cp = 0)
plot(matrix(swiss$Infant.Mortality), predict(object = rp, newdata = swiss) ,ylim = c(10,30),  xlim = c(10,30), main = "Rpart", ylab = "", xlab = "observed")
lines(seq(0,30), seq(0,30))
```

Resulting image:

[image: Results obtained for a single tree using randomForest package (left) and rpart (right)]:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that randomForest seems to be ignoring `nodesize`.  A bit of examination shows the same first few splits, but `randomForest` continues splitting where `rpart` does not, going to leaves with fewer than 5 cases.

Evidently this has been noticed before, but the documentation still hasn't been fixed: `nodesize` is actually better named (and described!) as `minsplit`:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417826/nodesize-parameter-ignored-in-randomforest-package
Setting `minbucket = 1` in your `rpart` call instead makes them more similar, although there are still differences.

A quick look into those differences, and it might just be tie-breaking.  The first right child, for instance, has two potential splits with the same impurity score according to `rp$splits`, and the two packages appear to choose different splits (`rp` takes "Agriculture", `rf` takes "Catholic").